# question about sequences and series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I would like to have your help about the proof of the following statement:

If the sequences of complex numbers $\{F_N\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}},\{G_N\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ have the following properties:

(i) $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |F_N|^{1/N}=0;$

(ii) $\limsup_{N \rightarrow \infty} |G_N|^{1/N}\leq 1;$

(iii) there exists $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$ and $C>0$ such that $|F_N|\leq C|G_N| \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |F_k|,$ for all $N \geq N_0$,

then there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N=0$ for all $N \geq N_1.$

This statement is in a paper without proof. Moreover, I only know the prove of this statement for the case when $G_N=1$ for all $N.$

The following is the proof for this special case.

Given the assumptions, there exists $M$ such that for all
$ N\ge M,$
$$ |F_N|^{1/N}<\frac{1}{C+2}, \quad \quad  \quad \quad  |F_N|\le C\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty|F_k|.$$ We claim that for those $N$'s,
 $$|F_N|\le\left(\frac{C}{C+1}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{C+2}\right)^N$$
 for any non-negative integer $n$. Then, letting $n\rightarrow \infty,$ we see that $|F_N|=0.$

To prove the claim, we use induction on $n.$ When $n=0,$ the formula follows immediately from $|F_N|^{1/N}<1/(C+2).$ In general, using induction  it follows that
 $$|F_N|\le C\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty|F_k|\le C\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{C}{C+1}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{C+2}\right)^k=\left(\frac{C}{C+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{C+2}\right)^N.$$

Could you provide me a proof of the statement or give me an idea of the proof? Thank you very much.

Masik

Answer (score 4):

The result is false. Define

$$ F_n = \frac{1}{n^n},\,\,G_n = (1+1/\sqrt n)^n.$$

Then $F_n^{1/n} = 1/n \to 0$ and $G_n^{1/n}=1+1/\sqrt n \to 1.$ However

$$\tag 1\frac{F_n}{G_n(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}F_k)} < \frac{F_n}{G_nF_{n+1}} =\frac{(n+1)(1+1/n)^n}{(1+1/\sqrt n)^n}.$$

The numerator is on the order of $n,$ while the denominator is greater than $2^{\sqrt n}$ for large $n.$ Since

$$\frac{n}{2^{\sqrt n}} \to 0,$$

we see $(1)\to 0,$ so certainly it is a bounded sequence, although all $F_n > 0.$